# Should I make an API that works for both my web app and mobile app or should keep them separate

Tags: android, ios, api, web-services, web-applications

I'm thinking of making a web application for a platform I have in mind and then if it becomes a success I'll later develop a mobile application for it. I was wondering if it would be better to make an API that would handle requests from the web app and mobile app or should keep the web app simple and make an API specifically for the mobile at a later date.

I was thinking about apps like Facebook and Twitter which started off as web apps then later became mobile apps and they went about this transition.

Comment: Have a single API for all clients, because it makes sense and would save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: As Henry mentioned, an API should be common to all your clients. It doesn't matter whether they are web or mobile. A quick guide you could look into: https://www.toptal.com/api-developers/5-golden-rules-for-designing-a-great-web-api